# producer to multiple subcriber paradigm

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a dispatcher which receives a message - and then 'fans' it out to multiple downstream environments.
Each set of downstream environment needs to consume this message.
Will it suffice to tag the different set of environments with different group.ID to force all the environments to consume the same message (1 producer - multiple subscriber broadcast).
If a particular environment (group) crashes,will it possible to replay the messages to the particular group only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is typically how you achieve such a data flow.

If you have multiple consumer groups subscribed to the same topics, they will all consume all messages. As you said, you use the `group.id` configuration to identify each consumer groups.

In addition each consumer group tracks its own offsets. So you can easily make a particular group replay part of the log without impacting the other groups. This can be achieved for example by using the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool with one of the reset options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how Kafka works. So long as the retention for the topic is configured such, then any particular consumer group can re-consume from any offset in the log, whether the beginning or just the last point from which it successfully read. All other consumers are unaffected.